# How to get shipment tracking using woocommerce rest api

Tags: rest, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have woocommerce instance and plugin "WooCommerce Shipment Tracking". How can I get shipment tracking for the orders using the rest api of woocommerce. I not found no information in the docs of that plugin and in the net.

Answer (score 1):

The tracking information for any plugin should be within the "meta_data" section of the orders API.

I built this plugin to add order tracking codes to woocommerce:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mc-woocommerce-tracking/